# To check the database having record or not

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have written the code to check the database having values or not,I want to move to one activity if database having record and to another if having no record.But my code moving to one activity always.

```
final Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllRecords();

        if(cursor!=null)
        {
            Intent i4=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyMenu.class);
            startActivity(i4);
            this.finish();
        }
```

Comment: no record doesn't mean the cursor is empty. you approach is wring, you should be counting records, not fetching them all

Comment: @njzk2 you are right.Its not a good way to fetch all records to check whether records available or not?  See this optimized solution   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13160185/to-check-the-database-having-record-or-not/13160258#13160258

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount() > 0)
    {
        Intent i4=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyMenu.class);
        startActivity(i4);
        this.finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to check record

```
public boolean isDataAvailable()
    {

        SQLiteDatabase db = mdbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT Count(*) FROM"+ TABLE_NAME, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
            int rowCount = cursor.getInt(0);
        if(rowCount>0)
        return true;
        else
            return false;   
        }catch (Exception e) {
            return false;   
        }
        finally {
            if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed())   cursor.close();
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

create a method to get count in your dbhelper and use this query
Example

```
"SELECT COUNT(word) as WORD_COL FROM " + WORD_TABLE
```

this will send you back the count so if count is 0 that means no records